# calling event within the same Window Form in Delphi Prism

Tags: events, listbox, click, delphi-prism

I am trying to call a click event from within another a method from the same Window Form file. It just won't work form me.

For instance:

```
  theClass = partial class(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
    method AlarmListBox_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);  
  private
  protected
  public
    method DoSomething;
  end;

  method theClass.DoSomething;
  begin
    self.AlarmListBox_Click; <<<this is where i want to call the click event
  end;
```

No matter what I do, it keeps raising compiler errors. I tried AlarmListBox.Click, AlarmListBox.performClick, etc.

Some of the errors I got:

1. There is no overloaded method "AlarmListBox_Click" with 0
   parameters.
2. Cannot access underlying event field

So, how do you fire an event within the same window Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to call the Event handler with the default parameters:

```
AlarmListBox_Click(self, EventArgs.Empty);
```

By passing self into the method you define that the source of the call was not the AlarmListBox but your form. You could also can pass in custom EventArgs that state that the Event was not raised because of a click on the AlarmListBox but from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the parameters of the method `AlarmListBox_Click`

Try this

```
AlarmListBox_Click(nil, nil);
```

Comment: @ RRUZ, parameters are part of an event. So, the caller shouldn't be able to pass them. Correct me if I am wrong. In Delphi, you would just call AlarmListBox_Click(self) or just AlarmListBox_Click;

Comment: In delphi you can call the procedure associated to the click event without parameters using the `Click` procedure like so `Button1.Click;` or executing the procedure associated to the event directly `Button1Click(nil);` . In .Net Winforms you can do this using the `PerformClick` method of the button. but this method is only exposed for some few controls like MenuItems, RadioButtons and Buttons.